# How to include Foundation Magaellan js in my webiste

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation

Can anyone tellme why in my [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/MI5Studio/pen/MBVmNJ) Magellan is not working but it does in this [FOUNDATIONS CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/ZURBFoundation/pen/gWKLqV)

I have included

```
foundation.core.js
foundation.min.js
foundation.magellan.js
foundation.smoothScroll.js
```

Can anyone tell me please what file is missing to make it work please.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show your HTML files which are pointing to magellan.js

Comment: I think I'm not pointing to magellan.js because I don't have that file

Comment: I have found the js files https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/tree/develop/js but it still not working.

Comment: Please use the dist files from the releases or use npm / yarn.

Comment: Anyone please ?

Answer (score 0):

Install foundation using NPM package manager as shown below:

```
npm install foundation-sites
```

Refer to magellin dependencies as mentioned below in your HTML file:

```
<script src="./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="./node_modules/foundation-sites/dist/js/foundation.js"></script>
<script src="./node_modules/foundation-sites/dist/js/plugin/foundation.magellan.js"></script>
<script src="./node_modules/foundation-sites/dist/js/plugin/foundation.smoothScroll.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for your response but I don't have any idea of NPM package or using the console. I do it manually

Comment: Try https://unpkg.com/foundation-sites@6.4.3/dist instead of ./node_modules/foundation-sites/dist for manual downloads.

Comment: Sorry Daniel I don't know what you are talking about.